# The output directory is under your source tree in meteor

Tags: meteor

how do I solve this

> The output directory is under your source tree
>   warning:the output directory is under your source tree
>   your generated files may get interpreted as source code
>   consider building into a different directory instead meteor build ../output

I apologize for my ignorance on this matter, I am new in the world of programming and meteor.  about my case. 1. I have a folder on Desk called “Findme” where I have the structure of my project (the code and everything which forms the application which works) 2. Then through the console I access that directory findme and then run the command meteor build/Desktop/MyApp --server = https: //findme.com, and start downloading. 3. But inside the console I also get the message indicated before and when it is finished, and I check the folder MyApp, it is empty. 4. And when I check the Findme folder it has created a folder named ~ and inside displays a file called Desktop/MyApp but it also doesn’t have any useful files, only winrar and nothing useful. 5. I am trying to generate the apk, could you please let me know what I might be doing wrong? Is there another way to generate the apk? I would appreciate it if you could help me!

Answer (score 1):

Your should specify a path for where to build your application that is outside of your project directory.

Otherwise this can lead to problems with Meteor's file watcher and as your error already pointed out:

> your generated files may get interpreted as source code consider
>   building into a different directory instead

So if your command uses a relative path, as used in `meteor build ../output` then it is important to call this command at the most upper project folder.

Consider the following project structure:

```
/myapp
  /client
  /import
  /server
```

If you call `meteor build ../output` from within `/myapp` it will generate the output folder as expected outside of the project:

```
/output
/myapp
  /client
  /import
  /server
```

However if you call it from within a subfolder, say `/myapp/imports` it may generate the output within the project like so:

```
/myapp
  /client
  /import
  /output
  /server
```

So keep this in mind when building your app.

Further readings:

https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild

Comment: thanks for answering me, I apologize for my ignorance on this matter, I am new in the world of programming and meteor. Regarding what you told me, I think I am doing what you said, but still I think I failed to explain myself better about my case. 1. I have a folder on Desk called “Findme” where I have the structure of my project (the code and everything which forms the application which works)